# Convert date into a timestamp format

Tags: php

I have the below codes which contain a date.

```
 echo $giorno_selcted;
    $post_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(stripslashes($giorno_selcted)));
```

$giorno_selected// echoes a date in this format 25-09-2012
$post_date// creates a date in format Y-m-d - 2012-09-25

What i need is to create two variables which will convert the $post_date to a timestamp i.e 2012-09-25 00:00:00 and 2012-09-25 23:59:59

```
$post_date_start = 2012-09-25 00:00:00
$post_date_finish = 2012-09-25 23:59:59
```

Thanks!

I have this query which permits me to print all the information inserted between two timestamps. But i get an error in the syntax which says, 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND' at line 1

Here is the code:

```
$post_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(stripslashes($giorno_selcted)));

$time_end = "23:59:59";
$time_start = "00:00:00";
$giorno_timestamp_start=$post_date.' '.$time_end;
$giorno_timestamp_start=$post_date.' '.$time_start;

$information="SELECT * FROM scheda_anagrafica WHERE time_inserted BETWEEN " . $giorno_timestamp_start. " AND ". $giorno_timestamp_end;
```

the time_inserted fieldis as a timestamp field..
Thanks

Comment: Just concatenate the times onto the string value output.  `$post_date . " 00:00:00", $post_date . " 23:59:59"`

Comment: You could go about adding 86399 to the unix timestamp value and then call `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` on it, but that isn't necessary.

Comment: You should ask new questions rather than edit old ones, but your problem is that you need to enclose the timestamp strings in single quotes `"BETWEEN '" . $giorno_timestamp_start . "' AND....`

Comment: Could you please be more specific? i still get an error, could you post your answer?

Comment: I got it working :):):):):)
thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple php

```
$post_date_start=$post_date." 00:00:00";
$post_date_start=$post_date." 23:59:59";
```

Comment: Needs a space before the time portion.